# Hadoop - How to switch from implementing the writable interface to use an Avro object?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro, writable

I’m using Hadoop to convert JSONs into CSV files to access them with Hive.

At the moment the Mapper is filling an own data structure parsing the JSONs with JSON-Smart. Then the reducer is reading out that object and is writing it to a file, separated by commas.
For making this faster I already implemented the writable interface in the data structure...

Now I want to use Avro for the data structure object to have more flexibility and performance. How could I change my classes to make them exchange an Avro object instead of a writable?

Answer (score 5):

Hadoop offers a pluggable serialization mechanism via the [`SerializationFactory`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/SerializationFactory.html).

By default, Hadoop uses the [`WritableSerialization`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/WritableSerialization.html) class to handle the deserialization of classes which implement the `Writable` interface, but you can register custom serializers  that implement the [`Serialization`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/serializer/Serialization.html) interface by setting the Hadoop configuration property `io.serializations` (a CSV list of classes that implement the Serialization interface).

Avro has an implementation of the `Serialization` interface in the [`AvroSerialization`](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/hadoop/io/AvroSerialization.html) class - so this would be the class you configure in the `io.serializations` property.

Avro actually has a whole bunch of helper classes which help you write Map / Reduce jobs to use Avro as input / output - there's some [examples in the source (Git copy)](https://github.com/apache/avro/tree/trunk/doc/examples/mr-example/src/main/java/example)

I can't seem to find any good documentation for Avro & Map Reduce at the moment, but i'm sure there are some other good examples out there.